# Restrict Logstash fields to particular index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have 3 indexes created in Logstash and I have written 3 different grok patterns to filter out multiple fields in documents.

When I add fields in one grok pattern for a particular index and restart Logstash, Index is created but the fields which I need to be used for that particular index gets added into another index also

For example, In grok file when I write **%{DATA:index_one_message}** than other indexes in Logstash also inherit "index_one_message" field

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Please provide the Logstash config.

Comment: **Logstash.yml**

`path.data: /var/lib/logstash`


`pipeline.id: main`

`path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf"`

`config.reload.automatic: true`

`config.reload.interval: 60s`
`log.level: debug`
`path.logs: /var/log/logstash`

Comment: And below is my conf file


**input {
    file {
        path => ""log_file_path
        tags => ["prod-1-index"]
 }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{index1}" }
    match => { "message" => "%{index2}" }
    }
}
output {
    if "prod1-index" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["ip:9200"]
            index => "index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            document_type => "index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}**

Comment: What is the file that you are parsing? Can you share a snippet?

Comment: The index name is being created anew every day by the date expression %{+YYYY.MM.dd}. You do not need document type as this option is deprecated in new ElasticSearch version 6.0 and the value "doc" will be used for 6.x versions.

Comment: @creedI can not share the log file here due to privacy issues
So as per user suggestion, I need to remove "document_type"?

This will fix my problem??

Comment: @creed [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html] as per this **document_type** is still available

Comment: From documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html "This option is deprecated due to the removal of types in Elasticsearch 6.0. It will be removed in the next major version of Logstash. This sets the document type to write events to. " It will not solve your problem but will remove unnecessary warnings from your log. If you do not provide even pseudo-code / pseudo-log what you are trying to parse and configuration it is very hard to answer your question, just giving hints or logic flow. From the pseudo log/config I can produce pseudo answer